# How to make one div fade in and the other fade out on hover?

Tags: jquery

Needless to say, I'm a beginner, especially when it comes to JavaScript and jQuery. I'm looking for a way to make one div fade in (via visibility, not opacity) and one fade out.

Here's an example of the HTML I'm going for.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="secondary" style="height:100px;width:100px;display:none;">
  When you hover over .main, .secondary fades in and .main fades out
 </div>
 <div class="main" style="height:100px;width:100px;">
  This text is visible by default
 </div>
</div>
```

I've looked around and couldn't find quite what I was looking for.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You cannot *fade* an element with *visibility* only. It has only two values, visible or hidden. There is nothing in between. You have to use opacity if you want to fade it.

Comment: What's wrong with using opacity? `visibility` only accepts `visible` and `hidden`, and you can't fade between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need some effects:

```
$('.secondary').fadeIn('fast');
$('.main').fadeOut('fast');
```

If not:

```
$('.secondary').fadeIn(0);
$('.main').fadeOut(0);
```

or if you want to keep place for the hidden element:

```
$('.secondary').css({ visibility: 'visible' });
$('.main').css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not make an element fade with only `visibility` as it only accepts `visible` or `hidden`.

You would need to use `opacity`.

```
var secondary = $('.secondary');
$('.main').hover(function() {
   secondary.stop().fadeIn(100);
   $(this).stop().fadeOut(100);
}, function() {
   secondary.stop().fadeOut(100);
   $(this).stop().fadeIn(100);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sUMtk/).

However, this poses a problem. You are fading out the element with the `mouseleave` event, so it will loop. Do you want the `mouseleave` event (I made an assumption you did)? If not, just replace `hover()` with `mouseenter()` and remove the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.secondary').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete
    });

     $('.main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
           // Animation complete
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main').trigger('mouseover', function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
            $('#secondary').fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="secondary" style="height:100px;width:100px;display:none;">
        When you hover over .main, .secondary fades in and .main fades out
    </div>
    <div class="main" style="height:100px;width:100px;">
        This text is visible by default
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$(".container div").click(function() {
    $(".main,.secondary").slideToggle();
});
```

here is the live demo:

> http://jsbin.com/izolik/edit#javascript,html,live